# encode NSString to CP1252 / windows1252

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, encode

All,

I have a `NSString` with a character in UTF8 format. I want to decode this to CP1252 / Windows-1252 format.
Actions to take:
- convert `NSString` to byte-array (UTF8-decode)
- encode byte-array to CP1252 / windows1252 format byte-array
- read first element from byte array

How can I do this? I have read a lot of documentation around `CFstring`, but I don't understand it.

What I have done:

```
    NSString *tileData = @"4¬";

NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[tileData substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] intValue]];
NSString *pos = [tileData substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];


// first attempt: create byte-array from NSString into UTF8. Then create NSString in CP1252 format.
    NSData *data = [pos dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",data);
    NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                              encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"htmlSTR =%@", htmlSTR);
    NSData *data2 = [htmlSTR dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data2 =%@",data2);


// second attempt: create byte-array from NSString into CP1252. Then create NSString in CP1252 format.
    NSData *data11 = [pos dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data11 =%@",data11);
    NSString *htmlSTR2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data11
                                              encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"htmlSTR2 =%@", htmlSTR2);
    NSData *data21 = [htmlSTR2 dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data21 =%@",data21);
```

Hope someone can help me or has an example.

Comment: Do you understand that not all UTF-8 (Unicode) strings can be encoded into CP1252?

Comment: `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding`? Is that what you're looking for? What have you tried? Did you search a little by yourself?

Comment: I have searched a lot and tried a lot of possible solutions. Off course! I know about the encoding, but how do I encode a string and use a bit array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
NSString *tileData = @"4æ";
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[tileData substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] intValue]];
NSString *pos = [tileData substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];

int position = [tileData  characterAtIndex:1];

if (position > 128) {

    NSData *data = [pos dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                              encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
    NSData *data2 = [htmlSTR dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];

    uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)[data2 bytes];
    NSMutableString *posstring = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:3];
    [posstring appendFormat:@"%d", bytes[1]];
    NSNumber *posgroot;
    posgroot = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[posstring intValue]];
    position = [posstring intValue];
    if (position <0) position +=256;
}
```

Strange thing is the difference between UTF8 and ASCII:
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec and http://www.asciitable.com

Also, I am not sure if the solution the best one is with the encoding to NSData, then encoding to NSString, the again encoding to NSDATA.

But this works for now!